# XMLGregorianCalendar date comparison

Tags: java, xml

How do i compare 2 instances of XMLGregorianCalendar to find which one is greater?
 One of the date variables have a value

```
date1 = 2009-02-23T05:54:17+05:30
```

and the other,

```
date2 = 2009-02-23T05:54:17.000
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could convert them both to `GregorianCalendar` and compare those (`Calendar` is `Comparable`). The semantics compareTo() method of Calendar is explicitly defined, and should work independent of the timezone:

> Compares the time values (millisecond
>   offsets from the Epoch) represented by
>   two Calendar objects.

So try this:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar date1 = ...
XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = ...
int result = date1.toGregorianCalendar().compareTo(date2.toGregorianCalendar());
```

If `result` is positive, then `date1` is "later" than `date2`

The `compare()` method on `XMLGregorianCalendar` itself does something rather peculiar, and doesn't look very useful to me.

Comment: why not use: date1.compare(date2) == DatatypeConstants.LESSER (as eg) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978328/how-to-compare-xmlgregoriancalendar-with-only-the-date-portion-day-month-year

goes into depth how XMLGregorianCalendar performs the comparison

Comment: Using date1.compare(date2) was not giving me logical results, the above answer is right.