# How to compare XMLGregorianCalendar with only the Date portion (day, month, year)?

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, jaxb, gregorian-calendar

I'm developing a webservice integrated with spring-struts web application, in XSD there is a XMLGregorianCalendar type property, let's say the property name is **trxDate**.

In SOAPUI testing application, if I inserted the value of trxDate with: **2013-02-21**, then I sent the soap xml request data and I printed the value in service method with: System.out.println(trxDate) method, the printout result is same as inputted: 2013-02-21.

Now, I'm trying to create a function to compare **trxDate** with current date. I know we can compare it using trxDate.compare(currentDate) method. The problem is I don't how to create XMLGregorianCalendar object set with current date with Date portion only (day, month, and year) to be used for comparing.

I tried with this code:

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 0);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, 0);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    System.out.println(xgc);
```

The result is:
2013-02-20T00:00:00.000+07:00

But I'm expecting:
2013-02-20

If use the date (**xgc**) to compare with **trxDate**:

```
int result = trxDate.compare(xgc);
```

The result is 2, which means: INDETERMINATE (from DatatypeConstants class). The proper result should be -1, 0, or 1.

So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to clear out the unwanted fields from the `GregorianCalendar`, it may be easier to create an un-initialized `XMLGregorianCalendar` and then copy just the fields you *do* want:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
xgc.setYear(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
xgc.setMonth(now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
xgc.setDay(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(xgc);
```

This avoids the round trip to String and back again that would be necessary if you were to use `newXMLGregorianCalendar(lexicalRepresentation)`

Comment: Whoa, I'm so confused there are many ways, which is better between your way and Blaise's way?

Comment: I just tried your code, there is a bit of mistake, you need to add +1 to the `xgc.setMonth()`, so the code should become: `xgc.setMonth(now.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);`. It seems XMLGregorianCalendar uses one-based month index.

Answer (score 4):

The [javadoc for XMLGregorianCalendar.compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#compare%28javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar%29) explains that it uses the [rules from the XML Schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-order) for the comparison, to which the javadoc links.

Section B.1. of the comparison algorithm states that both dateTimes must have exactly the same (sub)set of {year, month, day, hour, minute, second} fields defined.  If they don't, the result is indeterminate.  (The XML Schema spec uses `<>` in the algorithm description to indicate an indeterminate result.)

So if you have an XMLGregorianCalendar with just year, month and day defined, you must compare it with another XMLGregorianCalendar with just year, month and day defined.  Either you must parse it from a string, as Blaise suggested, or you must instantiate an XMLGregorianCalendar and call `setYear`, `setMonth` and `setDay` on it yourself.

Comment: This was an excellent answer, in my book.  I came across this issue because I was comparing 2 XMLGregorianCalendar instances but one had the time zone set.  Converting them into GregorianCalendar objects and using the compareTo() method provided me with the comparison logic I was looking for.  Otherwise, using XMLGregorianCalendar's compare() method will always return a DatatypeConstants.INDETERMINATE.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

You could also create your `XMLGregorianCalendar` this way:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(
            2012, 
            DatatypeConstants.FEBRUARY, 
            21, 
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, 
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, 
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, 
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, 
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    System.out.println(xgc);
```

---

You can use the following method:

- newXMLGregorianCalendar(String lexicalRepresentation)

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.datatype.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();

        XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2013-02-12");
        System.out.println(xgc);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
2013-02-12
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't aware there is such method, very quick and easy. Thanks very much. But I wonder if using my code way above, is it possible to achieve same result?

Comment: Whoa, I'm so confused there are many ways, which is better between your way and Ian's way?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(str);
    System.out.println(xgc);
```

this is a hint (order) to XMLGregorianCalendar to use `xsd:date` type where time is undefined

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for an alternative. This is what suited my requirements.

```
    ...

    date.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    date.setTime(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED,
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED,
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED,
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    ...
```

This remove the timezone and the timestamp.