# Sorting a Map by key (date,string)

Tags: java, maven, sorting

```
Map<XMLGregorianCalendar, String> SortedByTimeForJourney = new HashMap<XMLGregorianCalendar, String>();
```

I have to sort it by key(XMLGregorianCalendar).
I tried this

```
 SortedByTimeForJourney.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<XMLGregorianCalendar, String>comparingByKey()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

but it is showing
Type Parameter 'javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar'  is not withing its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<?super java.xml.datatype.XMLGregoringCalendar>'

I also tried to do by saving it in LinkedHashMap and also using Collections.util method but unable to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sort a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) by key, use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

As the javadoc says:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Since [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) doesn't implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), i.e. doesn't have a *natural ordering*, you have to specify a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-).

In Java 8+, use:

```
new TreeMap<>(XMLGregorianCalendar::compare)
```

In older versions of Java, use:

```
new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<XMLGregorianCalendar>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(XMLGregorianCalendar cal1, XMLGregorianCalendar cal2) {
        return cal1.compare(cal2);
    }
})
```

Comment: Yeah, It's working Thanks, Andreas. `TreeMap<XMLGregorianCalendar, String> SortedBy = new TreeMap<XMLGregorianCalendar, String>(new MyComp());`  and myComp like this. `class MyComp implements Comparator<XMLGregorianCalendar>{
        public int compare(XMLGregorianCalendar d1,XMLGregorianCalendar d2){
            return d1.compare(d2);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with key object [XMLGregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) is not [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

> Type Parameter 'javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar' is not
>   withing its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable'

You can use [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) which is a [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-).

Use as follows:

```
Map<Date, Integer> sortedByTimeForJourney = new TreeMap<Date, Integer>();
```

Get the time from XMLGregorianCalendar:

```
[XMLGregorianCalendar Instance].toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
```

Example: sortedByTimeForJourney as default sorted based on date.

```
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        Map<Date, Integer> sortedByTimeForJourney = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 12; i > 0; i--) {
            XMLGregorianCalendar xCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(2019, i, i, 0);
            sortedByTimeForJourney.put(xCal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime(), i);
        }
        System.out.println(sortedByTimeForJourney);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Actually, my Date is like this "2020-01-19T04:55:00" it is included with time also.

Comment: Hey Thanks, Naykam. I did like this Thankyou. `TreeMap<XMLGregorianCalendar, String> SortedBy = new TreeMap<XMLGregorianCalendar, String>(new MyComp()); and myComp like this. class MyComp implements Comparator<XMLGregorianCalendar>{ public int compare(XMLGregorianCalendar d1,XMLGregorianCalendar d2){ return d1.compare(d2); } }`

Answer (score 2):

The error message clearly states that - `XMLGregorianCalendar` doesn't implement `Comparable` and hence you won't be able to perform sorting operation. So, just to help you out quickly please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333686/xmlgregoriancalendar-date-comparison) post.

Also, using `TreeMap` is better option than `Reinventing the wheel`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Andreas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516033/379173) you can use this:

```
Map<XMLGregorianCalendar, String> SortedByTimeForJourney = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(XMLGregorianCalendar::toGregorianCalendar));
```

Comment: Simpler to just use `new TreeMap<>(XMLGregorianCalendar::compare)`